# How do I get geolocation to work in my phone?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, geolocation, gps

I want to get my gps coordinates in a browser on my phone when I visit my webpage running on my Apache webserver.
When I browse to this page:
https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=html5&file=geolocation
It shows a very simple example of how to show the gps coordinates using geolocation in Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<title>Get Visitor's Location Using HTML5 Geolocation</title> 
<script> 
    function showPosition() { 
        if(navigator.geolocation) { 
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
                var positionInfo = "Your current position is (" + "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + ", " + "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + ")"; 
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = positionInfo; 
            }); 
        } else { 
            alert("Sorry, your browser does not support HTML5 geolocation."); 
        } 
    } 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
    <div id="result"> 
        <!--Position information will be inserted here--> 
    </div> 
    <button type="button" onclick="showPosition();">Show Position</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

When I try it in Chrome on Windows I get the dialog to allow the site access my position, after I click "Allow" it shows the gps coordinates.

When I try it on my phone (iPhone) I get the dialog to allow the site access my position, after I click "Allow" it shows the gps coordinates.

Next step.
I load the page in internet explorer and then save the entire page to my Apache webserver folder.

Now I try the page on my server in Chrome on Windows and again I get the dialog where I allow the site access my position and after I click "Allow" it shows the gps coordinates.

Then I browse to the page on my server from my phone using any browser (duckduckgo, google, safari).
I get no dialog where I can allow the page access to my position and the coordinates are not shown.

Now I wonder what is stopping the same program that works on the tutorialrepublic site, from working on my phone when it's loaded from my webserver?
Obviously it has nothing to do with permissions not being set correctly on my phone, since it works on tutorialrepublic with the same settings.

What do I need to do to be able to make my own website that can show the gps coordinates on my phone?
In a simple way.

Comment: This is a good example, why a minimal, working example is useful. Please try to setup an own HTML-file with a test-script included and try out that one using different client devices.

Comment: Thank you feeela for your comment.
The example linked to above is minimal. But since the code works, there is no error to look for in the code.

I have edited the post to include the code.